# Setting button content to text OR image via Binding

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button, data-binding

How can I set button's content to text or image via data-binding? For now my only idea is to have 2 buttons, one with text and one with image, and hide one of them and show the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a single button.

You can put a Grid in the button with the Text and the Image in it, binding their visibility to show only one content at time.